# Android: Fill image with colors

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

[image]
[image]

I have a flask and I want to fill with a color based on integer value. E.g. if I pass 50 I want flask to be half full. I've made an research but I not sure which way to go.

**Option 1:** Extend progress bar class and  try to use 2 images one for the progress bar and second as progressDrawable.However I cannot find example that use completely different image as mine all examples use 9 patch images that look like progress bar.

**Option 2:** to extend View class and not Progressbar  and use bitmaps to in onDraw() method

**Option 3:** to use FloodFill Algoritham which I think is used only for a part of image

**Option 4:** ...

I hope you can point me into right direction.Any example or tutorials will be really appreciated.

Comment: You could use [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList) from android, but this will have a discrete number of images. To fill it up continuously you must implement a drawing algorithm on your costum views onDraw() method.

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what I was looking for. Clean and easy.